# Centering navigation menu

Tags: css, menu, center

Have been trying to sort out a centering of the navigation bar, just above the banner ([link](http://www.kolonel.net/shop)).  Ran through a few solutions on here, and I have played around with custom CSS to try certain variations, but still cant get what i am after.  Put simply, i am just wanting to get the menu centered.  I have read that it had to be fixed width, but then heard otherwise.  Hopefully the solution is something i can get my head around.

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
    to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
    to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
    [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
    that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
    see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
    it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: kolonel, Stack Overflow follows a pretty strict Q&A format and you don't really have a question here.

Comment: You have a ton of `float` properties that prevent the centering from being possible

Comment: See my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where. Bro 1 suggestion plz ask question properly other wise your question may be closed. These question may help in future to other people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove some of css rules from your style sheet and add few -  see below css to get desired layout.

**CSS:**

```
#header #navigation {
    /*float: left;*/ /* remove this property*/
}
#header #navigation {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    clear: none;
    /*float: right;*/ /* remove this property*/
    /*width: auto;*/ /* remove this property*/
    width: 285px; /* add width here to get the actual width of menu so we can make it center*/
}
```

**See screen shot:**

[image]